# How to build an object tree with recursive API calls?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

I want to construct a tree where each node is used in a API call to get the children nodes; starting at the root. And this will be done recursively until it reaches the `TREE_DEPTH_LIMIT`

```
export const search = async (searchTerm) => {

  try {
    const tree = {};
    await createTree(searchTerm, tree);
    return tree;
  } catch (err: any) {}
};

const TREE_DEPTH_LIMIT = 3;

const createTree = async (searchTerm, tree) => {
  if (counter === TREE_DEPTH_LIMIT) {
    counter = 0;
    return;
  }

  counter++;

  tree[searchTerm] = {};

  try {
    const res = await axiosInstance.get(
      `/query?term=${searchTerm}`
    );

 // res.data.terms is an array of strings
    res.data.terms.forEach((term) => {
      createTree(term, tree[searchTerm]);
    });
  } catch (err) {}
};
```

I am trying to do this recursively in the `createTree()` function above. It will use the searchTerm in the API call. Then it will loop through `res.data.terms` and call `createTree()` on each on the terms. But the output is not what I was expecting.

This is the output:

```
const tree = {
  apple: {
    apple_tree: {},
    tree: {},
  },
};
```

The expected output: (because the TREE_DEPTH_LIMIT is 3, it should have 3 levels in the tree)

```
const tree = {
  apple: {
    apple_tree: {
      leaf: {},
    },
    tree: {
      trunk: {},
    },
  },
};
```

Or is my solution completely incorrect and I should be going for another approach??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- `counter` seems to be a global variable, but that will not work out well as at each return from recursion, `counter` should have its value restored. It is better to use a local variable for that, so that every execution context has its own version for it. Even better is to make it a parameter and let it count down instead of up.
- The recursive call is not awaited, so in `search` the promise returned by `createTree` may resolve before all the children have been populated, and so you would work with an incomplete tree.
- Not a real problem, but it is not the most elegant that the caller must create a `tree` object and pass it as argument. I would redesign the functions so that `search` will create that object itself, and then use a recursive function to create *children* -- so I'd name that function `createChildren`, instead of `createTree`.

Here is a snippet that first mocks the `get` method so you can actually run it:

```js
// Mock for this demo
const axiosInstance = {async get(term) {const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));await delay(50);return {data: {terms: {"apple": ["apple_tree", "tree"],"apple_tree": ["leaf"],"leaf": [],"tree": ["trunk"],"trunk": []}[term.split("=")[1]]}};}}

const createChildren = async (searchTerm, depth) => {
  if (depth-- <= 0) return {};
  try {
    const res = await axiosInstance.get(`/query?term=${searchTerm}`);
    const promises = res.data.terms.map(async (term) =>
      [term, await createChildren(term, depth)]
    );
    return Object.fromEntries(await Promise.all(promises));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const TREE_DEPTH_LIMIT = 3;
const search = async (searchTerm, depth=TREE_DEPTH_LIMIT) =>
    ({[searchTerm]: await createChildren(searchTerm, depth)});

// Demo
search("apple").then(tree =>
    console.log(tree)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much trincot,it is working as expected. Much appreciated  :)